# UPDATE table_2 with data from table_1

Tags: mysql

I have two tables(table_1 and table_2). I want to copy ticket_cat for all those ticket_ids in table 1 and update table_2's ticket_cat for those IDs.

```
table_1
-------
ticket_id       ticket_cat
123             technical
456             non-technical       
789             technical
101             technical
111             non-technical
112             non-technical
113             non-technical

table_2
-------
ticket_id       ticket_cat
123             NULL
456             NULL
789             NULL
101             NULL
111             NULL
112             NULL
113             NULL
898             NULL
786             NULL
785             NULL
898             NULL
009             NULL
123             NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to do a JOIN on the tables and update the ticket_cat of table_2 table with the ticket_cat of table_1

```
UPDATE table_2  a
LEFT JOIN table_1 b
    on a.ticket_id = b.ticket_id
set
a.ticket_cat = b.ticket_cat
```

This should work for mysql (Note it may be different in different versions of SQL)

Answer (score 1):

You can use update with join

```
 update table_2
 inner join table_id  on table_2.ticket_id =  table_1.ticket_id 
 set table_2.ticket_cat = table_1.ticket_cat
```